# In Hibernate, how do I pass in date (without time) as a paramter to a CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate, date, jdbc, criteria

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.12.Final with Java 8.  I'm trying to build a query in which I pass in a date parameter.  However, I only want to pass in the year, month, and day as part of the date param, not the time.  So I have constructed this ...

```
        final java.sql.Date searchDate = new java.sql.Date(myObjectDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate().getTime());
    final ParameterExpression<Date> d = builder.parameter(Date.class);

    query.where(
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(d, objectPlanRoot.<Date>get(MyObject_.startDate)),
            builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(d, objectRoot.<Date>get(MyObject_.endDate))
            );

    result = null;

            result = entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter(d, searchDate)
                .getSingleResult();
```

However when my query is actually built and run, a time component is getting in the mix.  Through outputting the Hibernate log, I can see this param getting filled in my query ...

```
 '2013-06-30 05:00:00'>=myobject0_.START_DATE and '2013-06-30 05:00:00'<=myobject0_.END_DATE
```

Notice that there's the "05:00:00" filled in.  How can I eliminate this and only have the date component filled in?

Comment: Does the UTC time offset currently in effect in your local time zone happen to be `-05:00` or `+05:00`?

Comment: Sure does.  Regardless of what my local timezone is, I'd like Hibernate to build the query without using the time component.  How do I do that?

Comment: Have you investigated the possibility of creating the `ParameterExpression` as a `java.time.LocalDate` rather than a `Date` (which I assume is either `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`)?

Comment: That appear to have worked.  Thx!